# Insertar en una tabla MySQL con un SELECT recupendo el último ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura:
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos los estoy insertando de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, username_canonical, email_canonical, email, locked, enabled, 
  expired, credentials_expired, lastname, firstname, password, auth_source, status, picture_uri, 
  creator_id, language, registration_date, active, hr_dept_id, roles) 
  VALUES (:username, :username_canonical, :email_canonical, :email, :locked, :enabled, :expired, 
  :credentials_expired, :lastname, :firstname, :password, :auth_source, :status, 
  :picture_uri, :creator_id, :language, :registration_date, :active, :hr_dept_in, :roles)";
  $stmt = $DB2->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(":username", $mail[0]);
  $stmt->bindParam(":username_canonical", $mail[0]);
  $stmt->bindParam(":email_canonical", $user->email);
  $stmt->bindParam(":email", $user->email);
  $stmt->bindParam(":locked", $cero);
  $stmt->bindParam(":enabled", $uno);
  $stmt->bindParam(":expired", $cero);
  $stmt->bindParam(":credentials_expired", $cero);
  $stmt->bindParam(":lastname", $user->name);
  $stmt->bindParam(":firstname", $user->name);
  $stmt->bindParam(":password", password_hash($user->email, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
  $stmt->bindParam(":auth_source", $plataforma);
  $stmt->bindParam(":status", $cinco);
  $stmt->bindParam(":picture_uri", $user->picture);
  $stmt->bindParam(":creator_id", $uno);
  $stmt->bindParam(":language", $language);
  $stmt->bindParam(":registration_date", $fechaActual);
  $stmt->bindParam(":active", $uno);
  $stmt->bindParam(":hr_dept_in", $cero);
  $stmt->bindParam(":roles",$roles);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->rowCount();
  /*if ($result > 0) {
    $_SESSION["name"] = $user->name;
    $_SESSION["email"] = $user->email;
    $_SESSION["picture"] = $user->picture;
    $_SESSION["new_user"] = "yes";
    $_SESSION["e_msg"] = "";
  }*/

}
```

El campo id se inserta de manera auto incrementable , pero el campo user_id no se esta insertando. Sin este campo de user_id , el usuario no tiene permisos para acceder al sitio.

Para resolver esto estoy tratando de ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
    UPDATE user SET user_id = (SELECT MAX(user_id) + 9 FROM user)
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían ayudar a solucionarlo, por favor.

Comment: Si, así es ya corregí la pregunta porque ahora me lanza un error distinto con el UPDATE.

Comment: A ver si entendí, ¿la idea es establecer un `user_id` diferente a todos aquellos `users` que tengan el `user_id` igual a cero o `NULL`? ¿Por que usas la condición `id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user)`?

Comment: Quiero establecer en user_id lo mismo que está en id, el valor por defecto de user_id es NULL .

Comment: No sé pero tu `UPDATE` me da una malísima impresión, como si hubiera algún error de lógica en tu programa. No entiendo por qué  sumas `9`  a `user_id` ... Quizá con más datos se te pueda sugerir una mejor salida al problema. De todos modos, el error concreto que tienes ahora es que la tabla `user` , la cual interviene dos ¿o más veces?  en la consulta, es usada sin alias... por cada intervención distinta la tabla debe tener un alias, de lo contrario, el manejador no sabe a qué tabla referir qué datos o de qué tabla tomar qué datos.

Comment: En realidad el 9 es solo un ejemplo, lo real debería ser 1 para sumar 1 al último user_id insertado, me podrías facilitar un ejemplo del ALIAS que me comentas, por favor.

Comment: Si he entendido bien tu consulta, sería algo así: `UPDATE user u SET u.user_id = (SELECT MAX(user_id) + 9 FROM user)
WHERE u.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user);` De todos modos, como ya te comenté, no me parece una solución óptima. Ten en cuenta que si hay varios usuarios trabajando con la misma base de datos, podrías tener resultados inesperados.

Comment: La solución que me propones me sigue lanzando el mismo error . ¿De que otra manera podría insertat en user_id el mismo valor ya existente en id?

Comment: Prueba de esta manera: `UPDATE user a SET a.user_id = (SELECT MAX(b.user_id) + 9 FROM user b) ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En base [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145605/insertar-en-una-tabla-mysql-con-un-select-recupendo-el-%C3%BAltimo-id?noredirect=1#comment272934_145605), lo puedes hacer así

```
UPDATE user
    SET user_id = id
    WHERE user_id IS NULL
```